# Elasticsearch - return polygons in a given point (relation": "intersects returns union instead)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have multiple polygons in the index and I'm trying to return all the polygons in a given point.

But my query returns all the docs in the index even if it doesn't falls in polygon 1.

It gives me union instead of intersect.

Query is given below

Map Ref. http://geojson.io/#map=7/-31.775/144.382

```
PUT /example3
{

 "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "features": {
            "properties": {
              "geometry": {
                "type": "geo_shape"

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Sample data:

```
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "name": "Poly - 04",
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
        [
            [
              144.91670608520508,
              -37.82524314302977
            ],
            [
              144.96846199035645,
              -37.82524314302977
            ],
            [
              144.96846199035645,
              -37.78787789236923
            ],
            [
              144.91670608520508,
              -37.78787789236923
            ],
            [
              144.91670608520508,
              -37.82524314302977
            ]
          ]

        ]
      }
    }
```

Query:

```
    GET /example3/_search
    {
        "query":{
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match_all": {}
                },
                "filter": {
                    "geo_shape": {
                        "features.geometry": {
                          "relation": "intersects",
                            "shape": {
                                "type": "point",
                                "coordinates" : 
                                   [
                                      146.0138,
                                      -37.1734

                                    ]

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please update your code

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar I have updated the index and the data set